# The meaning of a math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The math problem shows bellow,

> A $\$550$ donation to community fund is to be divided among three organizations. The hospital is to get twice as much as the community recreation center and three times as much as the volunteer fire company. How much of the donation is to go to the community recreation center?

So I assume hospital donation is $H$, center donation is $C$, volunteer fire com is $V$. According to this sentence,

> The hospital is to get twice as much as the community recreation center and three times as much as the volunteer fire company.

So the formula is $H＝2C＋3V$. But actually it is supposed to be $H＝2C$ or $H＝3V$.

Is it wrong for me to see the word and as plus sign?
Thank you.

Comment: To put it simply, 'Yes'. The full meaning of the sentence is: The hospital is to get twice as much as the community recreation center; and the hospital is to get  three times as much as the volunteer fire company.

Comment: Yes it is wrong, it's saying H=2C and H=3V. If it wanted H=2C+3V it would explicitly say something about the values being combined. E.g. 'The hospital is to get twice as much as the community recreation center and three times as much as the volunteer fire company combined.'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [maths.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some precedent for using *and* to mean *plus* when sums are written out:

> **and** *conjunction*
>   1.6 Used to connect two numbers to indicate that they are being added together.
>   ‘six and four makes ten’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/and)

However, the sentence can also be parsed as a form of ellipsis:

- The hospital is to get twice as much as the community recreation center and (*the hospital is to get*) three times as much as the volunteer fire company.

> **and** *conjunction*
>   1 Used to connect words of the same part of speech, clauses, or sentences, that are to be taken jointly.
>   ‘She started out quietly and apologetically but her voice quickly gained firmness.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/and)

Both parts of the conjunction are comparisons of the form ***x*** times as much as **y**.

So both interpretations can be admitted. When there's ambiguity in the sentence, it can help to look at the context and the **conventions** governing that context. In your case, the context is that of simple maths problems presented in written form for translation to numeric form and subjected to further analysis. In such problems, my recollection is that the word *and* is usually used in the sense of *providing more information*, rather than *add up a sum*.

Nevertheless, maths problems can be open to obtuse interpretations, so using conventions to disambiguate can potentially backfire. The pragmatic advice is to *state your assumptions* - in this case, that you take *and* to mean *plus* or, more conventionally, that *the amount the hospital gets is the same as each of the two parts separately, not added together*.

Comment: I normally do have great respect for your answers and read them with interest. I shall delete my previous comments and flag the question for migration.

Comment: Thank you @Mick, I appreciate that. I'll delete my comments as well.

Comment: @Mick I’ve re-read my answer. I think I see where you were coming from if you were objecting to the last bit. I’ve now added to it.

Comment: I would be happier if you said that *and* should always be taken to mean a logical conjunction, unless it makes absolutely no sense to do so. Never mind. What you have to say is always interesting.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong. The word *and* is never used to mean *plus* in mathematics, although it is used like this in everyday English, e.g. "Two and two equals four." In mathematics, it is always "Two plus two equals four."

The sentence should be interpreted as:

> The amount that the hospital receives is twice as much as the community recreation center receives, and also three times as much as the volunteer fire company receives (but not the sum of these two amounts).

Your summary is also incorrect. It should be:

> H = 2C **and** H = 3V

Both equalities are true (at the same time), not one or the other.

Comment: _"although it is used like this in everyday English"_ OP's math problem is written in everyday English, which defeats your argument. (Note: I think your answer is correct, but you're using the wrong justification here)

Comment: The rule in maths is that *and* always means a logical conjunction. If the exam setter wanted to indicate addition, he would be expected to use *plus* or "the sum of". This is drilled into maths students from a very early age. If an exam setter used *and* when he meant *plus*, candidates would have valid grounds for complaint. It is as simple as that.

Comment: I agree when we're talking about a mathematical discussion, but not when it's a posed math problem. The point of a math problem is to have the **student** convert the linguistical (everyday English) to the mathematical (formula), rather than spelling it out for them. Using "plus" essentially gives away (part of) the answer and (partially) defeats the purpose of the posed math problem.

Comment: The question may have been couched in the way it was to test the candidates understanding of the term *and*. Assuming that it means *plus* will lead to an incorrect answer. The candidate will not be excused for making this mistake, and will probably be marked down for stating such an assumption. *And* always means logical conjunction in maths. Of course, "X equals the sum of A and B and C" is clear enough.

Comment: You're still not making the necessary distinction between explicitly talking about math, and posing a problem in everyday English (which implicitly can be solved by using math).

Comment: But the question is titled "The meaning of a math problem". Stop wriggling.

Comment: I'm not wriggling. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_(mathematics_education)): _"In science education, a word problem is a mathematical exercise where significant background information on the problem is **presented as text rather than in mathematical notation**. As word problems often involve a narrative of some sort, they are occasionally also referred to as **story problems** and may **vary in the amount of language used**."_ Note that the page on [math problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_problem) specifically refers to word problems for education.

Comment: All I can say is that I would be appalled if students were given full marks for assuming that *and* meant *plus* in this instance and arrived at an incorrect answer. No wonder we are not producing enough competent mathematicians. Maybe this question should be migrated to [maths.se], where the OP will get a straight answer.